# Can some one tell me why this code is moving the box left but not right? AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, coordinates

Very simple code, box moves to the left slowly.

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, framecheck);
function framecheck(event:Event):void
{ 
    box.x +=1.13;
    box.x -=1.2;
}
```

...and when we reverse the values, you'd think the box would move to the right slowly? but it doesn't?

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, framecheck);
function framecheck(event:Event):void
{ 
    box.x -=1.13;
    box.x +=1.2;
}
```

What is wrong with the code, how do i fix this?

Comment: A wild guess with no proof, but still. **DisplayObject** keeps its coordinates not in pixels, but rather in twixels (1/20 of pixel) which are **int** values, unlike **x** and **y** getters/setters, which are **Number**s. Thus every time you set, say, **x** it is being converted into internal value and also rounded. 0.05 is a maximum precision you get with **x**. I guess, your second piece of script gets **x** somehow rounded to the same value over and over again (given that 1.2 could be interpreted as 1.19999999999 easily). Solution: use a proxy **Number** variable then assign it to **x**.

Comment: this is just a simplified code, in my source code I am using variables and it does not work which is what lead me to simplify the code and try it directly. The bizarre part is that it works going left but not right.

Comment: Well, trace the proxy variable and see if it changes and how.

Comment: yea, its actually rounding DOWN to the nearest .05. so if i set x to .01, it rounds down to zero and if I set x to -.01 it rounds down to -0.05. This is why its moving left and not right.

Comment: Even more, it rounds on every assignment, so your -1.13 gets down to -1.15 first, then adding 1.2 adds a *tad* less first then gets rounded down to 1.15. BTW you can self-answer your question with this discovery.